# Hbase batch query example

Tags: batch-file, hbase

I read in "hadoop design pattern" book, "HBase supports batch queries, so it would be ideal to buffer all the queries we want to execute up to some predetermined size. This constant depends on how many records you can comfortably store in memory before querying HBase."

I tried to search some examples online but couldn't find any, can someone show me the example using java map reduce?

Thanks.

Dan

Comment: Do you mean running MapReduce loading or writing data to HBase? If that is the case this link is a good source of information http://hbase.apache.org/book/mapreduce.example.html

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want? You can save HBase Get object in a list and submit the list at the same time. It's a little better than invoke table.get(get) multiple times.

```
Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
pool = new HTablePool(conf, 5);
HTableInterface table = pool.getTable('table');
List<Get> gets = new ArrayList<Get>();
table.get(gets);
```